# Basic find -regex is not working under CentOS

Tags: regex, find

My understanding is that find traverses the entire file path to locate a string. As a result I cannot understand why the below regex is not working.

```
 find / -regex '^sysconfig$'
```

Should return /etc/sysconfig. 
Even simple regex such as `find / -regex 'bin'` returns nothing.

Am I missing something very simple?

Comment: Any reason you're using `-regex` instead of `-name`?

Comment: Nope, no reason. Why?

Comment: You can use `-name` (and globs if you need them) if you want to deal with just the filename, i.e. `-name 'sysconfig'`. Wouldn't use `-regex` unless you want to check something in the path as well (`-name` and `-path` might still be simpler), or need something beyond globs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change your regex to,

```
find / -regex '.*sysconfig$'
```

**OR**

```
find / -regex '.*/sysconfig$'
```

Because  `-regex` find expression matches the whole name, including the relative path from the current directory. So `.*` at first will match the preceding characters.

Answer (score 0):

In *no* regex implementation I'm aware of will the regex `^sysconfig$` match something like:

```
blah blah sysconfig
```

The `^` and `$` are start-string and end-string *anchors,* meaning that your test string will only match if it is *exactly* `sysconfig`, with no other text on either side. And, in fact, they're not even needed since `-regex` matches the entire string rather than substrings.

If you want all files ending with `sysconfig`, just use:

```
find / - regex '.*sysconfig'
```

Or use `'.*/sysconfig'` if you want all files called `sysconfig` in any directory.

Comment: My error, thanks. A quick question - `find -regex '^[/a-z_]*/$'`
How does this give an output of /?
I can put this into a new question if required.

Comment: More specifically are there any benefits of this regex being used over `find / -regex '^/$'`
Also I'm not sure about the purpose of the / inside [], does it mean match / or [a-z] character set or _? If so I think I understand - there is nothing before the / anyway.